# Using Core Audio in Cocoa Classes

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-audio, coremidi

I have been working through the examples in the [Learning Core Audio](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Learning-Core-Audio-Hands-Programming/dp/0321636848) book. This book does a great job of explaining the API's and how they work, but does not really talk about how to integrate them into Cocoa projects.

I really am not sure how to approach mixing the core audio/midi programming with obj-c classes. Are there any good tutorials out there that explain the standard practice in doing this?

Some of the questions that are in my mind at this point are:

- If I need a userdata struct, can I replace this with some kind of obj-c instance variables or @properties, or does this have to be a C struct?
- Where should I place my audio callback functions in my code? Can they just sit some place outside the @implementation?
- Since the callback functions are written in C, what do I do if I want to call an objective-C function or access a class property within them?

Comment: Objective-C objects are fundamentally not different from C structs. You might need `__unsafe_unretained` (and consequently be super careful with memory management) if you use ARC, thought. What's important is that you can get a pointer to what you want to pass.

Comment: You can put your audio callback functions wherever you want, even _inside_ the `@implementation` if you feel like it. You can have C definitions inside `@implementation` without any runtime impact. Also, provided you use the .m extension for your files, you can use Objective-C inside otherwise C-looking functions.

Comment: I didn't realise that it was ok to put C functions inside the @implementation! The source files I am using do have the .m extension but for some reason when I try to access a class property xcode will not auto complete it as though it is out of scope or something?

Comment: You can also put them outside the `@implementation` (but inside the same file anyways). It really doesn't matter. __However__, you can't access instance variables from a free C function: you need to have the object as a parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual practice is to pass your class instance as the userdata if the callback declares it as void*. Your callback can then cast it as the object and call any methods in it.

Comment: Except that in callbacks on Core Audio realtime threads (e.g. the render callback), you really shouldn't do anything that calls into the Objective-C runtime. You can access instance variables directly using object->variable syntax, as long as they're declared using @public.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. I didn't realise that it was ok to pass objects as a void* and then cast them back. I will have an experiment!

Comment: @AndrewMadsen So i'm guessing for performance reasons when doing real-time audio processing it is best to keep things strictly within C for callbacks? One callback where I was thinking it would matter less would be something like a MIDIReadProc, say I wanted to update a UI using a IBOutlet property for example

Comment: I'm not sure about MIDIReadProc. I think you're fine as long as the callback is not being called on a realtime thread. I think the primary place where realtime threads are called is render callbacks. (I'm far from a Core Audio expert. I learned everything I know from Chris Adamson's book and blog posts like [this one](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/why-coreaudio-is-hard.html).)

Comment: @tom1990 you should never update the Cocoa UI from a secondary thread. You should make use of `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` to do any updating of UI. I think MIDIReadProc is still a realtime situation,you don't want to drop any MIDI events because the callback took too long

Answer (score 1):

C is a proper subset of Objective C.  So you can just use C data types and calling conventions to integrate Core audio with Cocoa.  C source code can go in separate .c files, as well as inside Objective C implementations.  Objective C objects can be treated as pointers to C structs inside a C callback.

Also, using Objective C messaging inside real-time Core Audio callbacks is not recommended.